# Using Django sessions to store logged in user

Tags: django, session, nosql, django-sessions

I'm creating a REST-centric application that will use a NoSQL data store of some kind for most of the domain-specific models. For the primary site that I intend to build around the REST data framework, I still want to use a traditional relational database for users, billing info, and other metadata that's outside the scope of the domain data model.

I've been advised that this approach is only a good idea if I can avoid performing I/O to both the RDBMS and NoSQL data stores on the same request as much as possible.

My questions:

1. Is this good advice? (I'm assuming so, but the rest of these questions are useless if the first premise is wrong.)
2. I'd like to cache at least the logged on user as much as possible. Is it possible to use Django sessions to do this in a way that is secure, reliably correct, and fault-tolerant? Ideally, I would like to have the session API be a safe, drop-in replacement for retrieving the current user with as little interaction with the users table as possible. What legwork will I need to do to hook everything up?
3. If this ends up being too much of a hassle, how easy is it to store user information in the NoSQL store (that is, eliminate the RDBMS completely) without using django-nonrel? Can custom authentication/authorization backends do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pondering using the same approach for my application and I think it is generally safe but requires special care to tackle cache consistency issues.

The way Django normally operates is that when request is received, a query is run against a Session table to find a session associated with a cookie from the request. Then, when you access `request.user`, a query is run against a User table to find a user for a given session (if any, because Django supports anonymous sessions). So, by default, Django needs two queries to associate each request with a user, which is expensive.

A nice thing about Django session is that it can be used as a key, value store without extending any model class (unlike for example User class that is hard to extend with additional fields). So you can for example put `request.session['email'] = user.email` to store additional data in the session. This is safe, in a sense, that what you read from `request.session` dictionary is for sure what you have put there, client has no way to change these values. So you can indeed use this technique to avoid query to the User table.

To avoid query to the Session table, you need to enable session caching (or store session data in the client cookie with `django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies`, which is safe, because such cookies are cryptographically protected against modification by a client).

With caching enabled, you need 0 queries to associate a request with user data. But the problem is cache consistency. If you use local in memory cache with write through option (`django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache` with `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db`) the session data will be written to a DB on each modification, but it won't be read from a DB if it is present in the cache. This introduces a problem if you have multiple Django processes. If one process modifies a session (for example changes `session['email']`), other process can still use an old, cached value.

You can solve it by using shared cache (Memcached backend), which guarantees that changes done by one process are visible to all other processes. In this way, you are replacing a query to a Session table with a request to a Memcached backend, which should be much faster.

Storing session data in a client cookie can also solve cache consistency issues. If you modify an email field in the cookie, all future requests send by the client should have a new email. Although client can deliberately send an old cookie, which still carries old values. Whether this is a problem is application depended.

Comment: Wow, very nice/thorough answer, thanks. +1 for you. I was definitely thinking of using memcached in production; for development, with a local server with local user, it should be sufficient to use the local in-memory cache, right? (Since there's only one Django process in that scenario)

Comment: And one more question-- if I just wanted to store in the session the *entire `User` model* corresponding to the logged in user, would that work, or do I need to serialize it first?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure in case of the Django development server, local cache should be sufficient. The problem arises when you use a server with multiple workers (for example gunicorn with -w parameter). I've checked that putting User object in a session dictionary works, but not in the way that you would probably need. User is correctly serialized and deserialized, but on access a query is run against a User table, so benefits of caching are lost. For my application, I plan to manually copy and update all relevant fields from the User object to the session dict.

Comment: I expected as much. Storing fields will be fine for my purposes, I think. Thanks for the excellent responses.