# Is partial form a good practice in Django?

Tags: django

I'm new in Django and I try to find out if saving partial forms are a good practice or not. For example, I have Poll App and Candidate model with four fields: `name`, `surname`, `targets` and`biography`. And I have a form where I have to fill all these fields. But if user only finished fill `name`, `surname` and `targets`, but even din't start filling `biography` field, how can I save his draft to user can finish it later and don't make any security mess?

models.py:

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    biography = models.TextField()
    targets = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

forms.py

```
class CandidateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate

        fields = [
            'name',
            'surname',
            'biography',
            'targets',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'biography': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3})
        }
```

I will be happy to see all ideas.

Comment: plz provide your models.py file inside pool app. i say you details.

Comment: Done. Maybe it will be useful so I have added also a forms.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I save his draft to user can finish it later and don't make
> any security mess?

You can either save the data to DB if you have designed the models to accept null or blank values, Or you can use Django sessions to temporarily store the form data until the form is completed...

In both case the security is not an issue since just like a DB access the django session data is also stored in a database and not in the browser... and so the end users cannot easily mess with the data...

[check the following answer if you would like to know more...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424474/8401179)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here :-

**models.py:**

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    biography = models.TextField()
    targets = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

If you put default='your default value':-

**models.py:**

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    biography = models.TextField(default=' ')
    targets = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

I think this is right what you need

Comment: This is not I found because it was just an example that targets might be unfilled. In reality, it could be biography, surname or other fields. But thank you. I am appreciate your answer!

Comment: Sorry for this. Now check it....

Comment: Oh, I've got in. This is a nice solution too, because you don't have to use any database and you need to only use 'default' property. I guess using your solution and the solution with database by SANGEETH SUBRAMONIAM simultaneously is a good way to solve the problem. Thanks!